# Background positioning help - expandable content area with shadows?

Tags: html, background-image

I'm working on a design that has some image based shadows (can't use CSS3 as they're not simple shadows) on the content area, which needs to be flexible vertically.

The design has a white content area, with a shadow in the top right edge, a shadow on the bottom right corner and all the way along the bottom edge as you can see on the site.

In order to try and do this I've created a wrapper to try and deal with the top shadow, and then applied the background image to the bottom of the main content area within it to deal with the bottom shadows. I've then made the background white. My thinking is that the 'bottom' shadow image will always stick to the bottom of the content area no matter how much it expands, and the white colour will handle the rest.

Problem is, the shadow image obviously sits inside the div, and there is no way to make it hang 'out' of the container... so as you can [see here](http://jamesperrett.co.uk/ightham/index.html) it looks weird.

[JSFiddle of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2dSD/6/), you can see top shadow looks fine but the bottom one is sitting within the div so get's coloured in by the background colour too.

I can't get my head around a solution for this. Essentially that shadow sitting inside the div should be sitting neatly outside it.

**HTML for quick reference:**

```
<div id="contentWrapper">
      <div id="content">
            <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>
            <h2>Content in here</h2>
      </div>
</div>
```

**CSS for wrappers and content areas:**

```
#contentWrapper{
    background-image:url('../img/top-content.png');
    background-position:top right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:820px;
    margin-left:200px;
}


#content{
    background-image:url('../img/bottom-content.png');
    background-position: bottom right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:#FFF;
    width:802px;
}
```

Comment: Could you make a fiddle for us? It makes it a bit easier to mess around with it.

Comment: Sorry I'm so used to using Chrome dev tools I always forget :P Chekc back in a few mins, thanks! :)

Comment: Done :) Any help appreciated!

Comment: Okay, I am not sure I understand what your issue is. The image is being displayed in the bottom right as you specified. Are you saying that the shadow is not perfectly aligned with the bottom of the content div? If so, that would be because your image has white space on the bottom.

Comment: The shadow should be outside the white space, representing a shadow around the white area. But it can't, obviously because that div also has a white background colour. I can't figure out how to do it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [multiple backgrounds](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/):

```
#contentWrapper{
    background:url("http://jamesperrett.co.uk/ightham/img/top-content.png") no-repeat right top,
        url('http://jamesperrett.co.uk/ightham/img/bottom-content.png') no-repeat bottom right;
    width:820px;
    margin-left:200px;
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2dSD/8/

**EDIT**:

To fix the bottom shadow, use

```
#contentWrapper{
    background:url("http://jamesperrett.co.uk/ightham/img/top-content.png") no-repeat right top,
        url('http://jamesperrett.co.uk/ightham/img/bottom-content.png') no-repeat bottom right;
    width:820px;
    margin-left:200px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2dSD/13/

---

But that's CSS3. If you want it to work on old browsers, add a new container:

HTML:

```
<div id="contentWrapper"><div>
      <div id="content">
            <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>
            <h2>Content in here</h2>
      </div>
</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#contentWrapper{
    background:url("http://jamesperrett.co.uk/ightham/img/top-content.png") no-repeat right top;
    width:820px;
    margin-left:200px;
}
#contentWrapper>div{
    background:url('http://jamesperrett.co.uk/ightham/img/bottom-content.png') no-repeat bottom right;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2dSD/17/

Comment: This has fixed the bottom right corner shadow, but the bottom edge has no shadow.